# Redux toolkit alert removal setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm totally new to the redux-toolkit and still learning it, I'm kind of blocked at this step as I don't know how to implement it with redux-toolkit.

I have a system of toasts build in my redux store and this was my action.

## MY Action

```
const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) => (dispatch) => {
  const id = uuidv4();
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, alertType, id },
  });

  setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
};
```

## My Old reducer

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case SET_ALERT:
      return [...state, payload];
    case REMOVE_ALERT:
      return state.filter((alert) => alert.id !== payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I was thinking about creating a react component to render when an alert array is longer than 0 with useEffect but I think it would be overkill.

I was thinking also about creating createAsyncThunk action but I need to return the value of the alert so I can't set setTimeout as the function would return.

Is there a way to get the dispatch function in the reducer so it would dispatch removeAlert after timeout?

```
const initialState: [] = [];
const alertSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'alert',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAlert(state, action) {
      const id = uuidv4();
      [...state, action.payload];
      toast[action.payload.alertType](msg);
      setTimeout(() => dispatch(removeAlert(id)), timeout);
    },
    removeAlert(state, action) {
      return state.filter((alert) => alert.id !== action.payload);
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with hand-written thunk

https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#async-logic-and-side-effects

```
const initialState: [] = [];

const alertSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'alert',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    sA(state, action) {
      [...state, action.payload];
      toast[action.payload.alertType](action.payload.msg);
    },
    rA(state, action) {
      return state.filter((a) => a.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
  },
});

export const { sA, rA } = alertSlice.actions;

export function alert(msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const id = uuidv4();
    const obj = {
      msg,
      alertType,
      timeout,
      id,
    };

    dispatch(sA(obj));
    setTimeout(() => dispatch(rA(id)), timeout);
  };
}

export default alertSlice;
```